# How to clone the struct include `Rc<Fn(T)>`?

Tags: rust

I want define a type, include `Rc<Fn(T)>`, `T` **not** required `Clone` trait, example code:

```
use std::rc::Rc;


struct X;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Test<T> {
    a: Rc<Fn(T)>
}


fn main() {
    let t: Test<X> = Test {
        a: Rc::new(|x| {})
    };
    let a = t.clone();
}
```

can't complie, error message is:

```
test.rs:16:15: 16:22 note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `X : core::clone::Clone`, `X : core::clone::Clone`
test.rs:16:15: 16:22 help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following trait defines an item `clone`, perhaps you need to implement it:
test.rs:16:15: 16:22 help: candidate #1: `core::clone::Clone`
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How to correct my code?

Comment: `#[derive(Clone)]` is for simple cases, it does not work in every case. Implement `Clone` manually.

Comment: @bluss it's work, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `#[derive(Clone)]` is rather stupid.  As part of its expansion, it adds a `Clone` constraint to *all* generic type parameters, whether or not it actually needs such a constraint.

As such, you need to implement `Clone` manually, like so:

```rust
struct Test<T> {
    a: Rc<Fn(T)>
}

impl<T> Clone for Test<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Test {
            a: self.a.clone(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "How has no one answered this yet?  Quick!  Quick!"

Comment: Right, that's how it works :) I'll remove mine then.